# PDO SQLite Cannot Open Database

Tags: php, sqlite, iis, pdo

I do alright with PHP in Linux environments, but I'm working on a PHP application that uses PDO's sqlite on IIS 8 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Reading from the database works fine; attempting to insert or update results in the rather unhelpful error, "unable to open database file"

### Code that works fine:

```
if (!($db = new PDO('sqlite:assets/database.db'))) { ?>
    ...
} else {
    $stmt="SELECT
             ... ";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($stmt);

    $stmt->execute(array(":person" => $this->uid));
}
```

### Code that doesn't work:

```
if (!($db = new PDO('sqlite:assets/database.db'))) { ?>
    ...
} else {
    $stmt = "INSERT INTO bills(date, label, categ, amount, timestamp) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($stmt);
    var_dump($stmt->errorInfo()); 
    // yields : array(3) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL }

    $stmt->execute([$fData['date'], $fData['label'], $fData['categ'], $fData['amount'], $fData['timestamp']]);
    var_dump($stmt->errorInfo()); 
    // yields : array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "HY000" [1]=> int(14) [2]=> string(28) "unable to open database file" }
}
```

### Things I've tried already:

- Making sure the IIS user has read/write permissions of the database file, [per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666834/php-pdo-sqlite-unable-to-open-database)
- Making sure the IIS user has read/write permissions of the directory containing the database file.  [per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319112/sqlite-read-only-database)
- Check IIS error logs for any indication of what's going on. (The only thing present is an unrelated warning caused by this request failing.)
- Making sure it works with another Database (it works fine with mySQL, but sqlite is a hard requirement for the final application.)

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was with the specific user account involved in running PHP on IIS.  Apparently, the user is the IUSR, which is oddly *not* a part of the IIS_Users group.  Thus, adding IUSR to the list of permitted users solved the problem, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10033126/missing-iusr-account-on-windows-server-2008-r2-iis7-5), which I wish had come up in searches a few days ago.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue but working with Apache, turns out that the origin of the problem was the same.

Sqlite will need to create additional files in the directory to hold transactional data and since it does not have permission to write in the current folder it will give the that error while reading works fine.